# Jquery dropdown variable height

Tags: jquery

So I want to create a dropdown div menu similar to that on starbucks. My initial menu is a simple UL with links, but no second tear lists like a normal dropdown. I have Jquery to handle the hover on the links and to show a div with the corresponding class. Ie hover over link with id 'blog' .. show div with class blog. This works pretty well, the problem is with the slideUp slideDown transitions. Instead of just changing height and showing the new menu (So if div1 has a height of 100px , div2 a height of 200px ... instead of the just changing the height (like on starbucks) my transition slides all the way up, and then back down to the new height.

How could I have it so the height would just slide up or down to the new height... and then when the hover leaves it slides all the way up.

Currently I have a container div and the specific content divs in this. The container div slides down and the content divs just hide and show when needed.

```
 <script>
   $('#menu a').hover(function(){

    var id =(this.id);

    switch(id)
    {
        case 'blog':
        $('.blog').show();
        $('#dropdown').slideDown();

        break;
         case 'videos':
        $('.videos').show();
        $('#dropdown').slideDown();

        break;
        case 'tutorials':
        $('.tutorials').show();
        $('#dropdown').slideDown();

        break;

    };
    },
    function(){

    $('#dropdown').slideUp();
    $('.ddmenu').hide();

   });
   </script>
```

-------------FIXED

Fixed it. Well hacked it. I decided to use a .hover over the menu container first and on hover out it animates the height to 0... inside the however function is nothing which seems a bit wasteful but using .mouseout didn't work :/

heres the code:

```
 <script>
       $('#menu ').hover(function(){

    },
    function(){

    $('#dropdown').stop().animate({height:0},200);
    });

   $('#menu a').hover(function(){

    var id =(this.id);

    switch(id)
    {
        case 'blog':
        $('#dropdown').stop().animate({height:200},300);

        $('.blog').show();



        break;
         case 'videos':
        $('#dropdown').stop().animate({height:100},300);
        $('.videos').show();


        break;
        case 'tutorials':
        $('#dropdown').stop().animate({height:300},300);
        $('.tutorials').show();


        break;
            case 'none':
        $('#dropdown').stop().animate({height:0},300);
           $('.ddmenu').hide();       

        break;

    };
    },
    function(){


    $('.ddmenu').hide();



   });


   </script>
```

Comment: You'll need to change the code and `animate()` the height instead, as `slideUp()` does just that, it slides all the way up.

Comment: Maybe use animate height instead of slide up and down?

Comment: I've just tried sticking :

$('#dropdown')animate({ height:'400px'; },500 );
within the switch element along with the show and it doesn't work at all .. was my syntax wrong?

Comment: I've got the height animate to work but the same thing happens. I've noticed it's because the function is called when the #menu a is hovered upon ... so the hoverout is called between links which slides it up. I could do it on #menu hover but I use the a in order to get the link id which gives me the correct div id to show. How could I work around this? (Is there a way to get the hovered link id even if I use #menu.hover?

Comment: I also tried wrapping it all into a #menu.hover function too but for some reason to make it work I have to hover over a link and then hover out ... and then each time I hover over it works fine.